# Need Help Graphing a Rational Function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been struggling to graph the function [image]correctly.

I don't know how to add the asymptote "x = 1", where x=f(y). I see that pgfplots automatically adds this asymptote, but then how do I make it a black color and dashed style?

Below is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin = -20,
    xmax = 20,
    ymin = -20,
    ymax = 20,
]
%f(x)
\addplot [
    domain=-20:20, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
]
{(3*x+6)/(x-1)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}

%Vertical Asymptote
%\draw [dashed] (1,20) -- (1,-20);
%\addplot[domain=-20:20,variable=\x,style=dashed] {1};
\draw[domain= 1:1.1,variable=\y,style=dashed] plot ({1},{\x});

%Horizontal Asymptote
\addplot [style=dashed, domain=-20:20]{3};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and here is what the graph currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! The function has two special points, one when the numerator changes its sign, and one when the denominator changes its sign. So it makes sense to split the plot in three parts. (Currently the middle part is not visible, but it may become visible if you change different values for `ymax`. I also added `unbounded coords=jump`.) The asymptotes can be added via `\draw`, where the end points are determined via `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` etc. (BTW, when you say `variable=\y` the variable in the plot also has to become a `\y`, but I replaced the plot by a straight line.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin = -20,
    xmax = 20,
    ymin = -20,
    ymax = 20,
]
%f(x)
\addplot [unbounded coords=jump,
    domain=-20:-2, 
    samples=41, 
    color=red,
]
{(3*x+6)/(x-1)};
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}

\addplot [unbounded coords=jump,
    domain=-2:1, 
    samples=16, 
    color=red,
]
{(3*x+6)/(x-1)};

\addplot [unbounded coords=jump,
    domain=1:20, 
    samples=46, 
    color=red,
]
{(3*x+6)/(x-1)};

%Vertical Asymptote
%\draw [dashed] (1,20) -- (1,-20);
%\addplot[domain=-20:20,variable=\x,style=dashed] {1};
\draw[dashed] (1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
(1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},3) --
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, this really cleared it up. Thank you so much! :)